# Nested records in orientDB and querying the same

Tags: graph, gremlin, orientdb

I need to store a graph with vertices and edges.My use case is as follows:

Each vertex has following  properties.

There are some basic properites like name , age etc and then there are some record kind of properties

```
Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 Prop4 Pro5
"xyz"  "1"   "2"  "ha"   7
"abc"  "1"  "3"   "aks" 8
```

Note:This are the properties only one vertex.These are kind of nested properties.Nested properties are kind of records in relational DB.

1)Now i want to fire SQL like queries on these nested properties /records.IS this possible?
Eg Find for each vertex valueOf Prop5 only if Prop2="1" .These are kind of relational DB queries.

Eg2: count number  of nested records with Prop5 value = 7

IS this supported in OrinetDB ?If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed records inside records. If are multiple records to be embedded use an EMBEDDEDMAP, EMBEDDEDSET or EMBEDDEDLIST. To query it you could do something like:

```
select Prop5 from blabla where embeddedProperties contains ( Prop2 = '1' )
```

Assuming embeddedProperties it's a list of embedded records (EMBEDDEDLIST).

Comment: I have one class MyClass which has List<Property> .Property is another class defined by me.When i registered these two classes via java code it created two tables .MyClass and Property . In my case is List<Propery> embededList? .If yes then why is seperate table created for it?Am i doing something wrong?.The query is working fine  but i want to know if its correct way

Comment: By default is NEVER embedded, but linked. If you want it embedded declare a property in the schema of type EMBEDDEDLIST.

Comment: Can an embedded list type be nested inside another embedded list?